# How to change entry text size? (Tkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, text

So I am trying to change the text in a entry to be bigger. So far I could only make the actual text box bigger, but not the user inputted text inside. How would I change the user-inputted text in an entry to be bigger and is there a way to change it's font as well? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried `tk.Entry(..., font=("", 30))`

Comment: if you can share related part of the codes where you are fumbling, then someone might be able to help you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out how to, I tried to do `font=` but it said that there wasn't such a thing as `font`. However this was because I added that in the `.pack` line...

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
from tkinter import *

website_entry = Entry(font=(font_family, font_size))
```

font size can be set by using the 'font' attribute when creating the Entry object. Font size should be an int and font-family a string.

Comment: This isn't a very good example. `font-size` looks like you're subtracting `size` from `font`.